# Coffeescript classes and scope

Tags: coffeescript

While learning coffeescript, I'm trying to create an instance of class A inside a method of class B, this is the code:

```
class @A
  constructor: (@x) ->
  show: ->
    alert @x

class @B
  constructor: (@y) ->
  show: ->
    a = new @A("eric")
    alert a.x
    alert @y

b = new @B("daniel")
b.show()
```

the error is TypeError: undefined is not a function.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `@` is just another way of saying `this` in CoffeeScript. That's all it means.
2. Classes are (more or less) just variables or properties like any other in CoffeeScript.

So when you say `@A`, you're just looking for the `A` property of `this` and your `show` is really saying:

```
a = new this.A("eric")
```

In that context, `@` will be an instance of `B` and `B`s don't have `A` properties. Instead you should just say:

```
a = new A('eric')
```

Using `@` when defining a class:

```
class @A
  #...
```

is just a way to make a class globally available. At the top level, `@` will (almost always) be `window` in a browser so you're really saying:

```
class window.A
  #...
```

and `window` properties are globals. Keep in mind that each CoffeeScript [file is wrapped in a function](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope) when it is converted to JavaScript:

> Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function:  `(function(){ ... })();` This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation of the `var` keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the global namespace by accident.

So if you just said:

```
class A
```

then `A` would only be available to other code in that file. Saying:

```
class @A
```

makes `A` global.

If you're only working with one file then you don't need the `@`s on your classes:

```
class A
  constructor: (@x) ->
  show: ->
    alert @x

class B
  constructor: (@y) ->
  show: ->
    a = new A("eric")
    alert a.x
    alert @y

b = new B("daniel")
b.show()
```

Don't get in the habit of prefixing everything with `@`, only use it on classes when you need it and you know exactly what it will do. Even when you need it, there are better ways: use require.js to manage your dependencies, use an global application-specific object to manage scopes, ...